# Determining pulses per quarter note

Tags: matlab, midi

I'm currently using [this code](http://www.kenschutte.com/midi) (specifically the matrix2midi.m file) to write a MIDI file in Matlab. All is fine except that my tempo does not match what I specified.

I currently have what I want the tempo to be in BPM. I then use the following formula to convert into a tempo format used by MIDI files ([taken from](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/midifile/ppqn.htm)):
Tempo = 60,000,000/BPM
I then also have to set the pulses per quarter note (PPQN):
PPQN = Tempo/TimeBase

I've no idea what the time base refers to and how to get it.
Is the PPQN something which is by the hardware?

Answer (score 3):

MIDI clock sends a tick 96 times per quarter note.

120 BPM = 120 Quarter Notes per Minute

60 / 120 = 0.5 seconds per beat

500ms / 96 = 5.208333ms per clock tick.

Comment: @Brad, you assume that beat is equal to quarter note, but it's not always so.

Comment: @golergka, Obviously you can use whatever you want instead of quarter notes for your beat.  This doesn't change the math.

Comment: @brad, Sorry for being anal, it's just your answer is pretty high on google searches about this, and if someone would take this answer for granted without properly analyzing it, he would run into bugs later on. I made this stupid mistake myself, and just wanted to warn others.